# Does profit from the tourist attraction culture buildings go to the city coffers?

Tags: simcity-2013

The tourist attraction buildings have an hourly expense like other special buildings, so I know their baseline cost. But they also have a profit associated with them, so I'm wondering if this generates (or takes) money from the city coffers.

In this example, the Leaning Tower of Pisa costs §7,320/day (§305/hr) outright. Does the daily loss bring that number to §12,836?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The expenses from your tourist attractions come directly from your city coffers. No matter what kind of business your attraction does, you are being charged (in this case) $305/hr for having it. It operates just like a park would in that sense...

However, any revenue brought in by the attraction is added directly to your budget as well. If you exceed your break even point, this will show on your budget view balance sheet as a net gain. This item on the balance sheet is labeled as "city specialization"

The "Profit" number in red on your picture above is a bit misleading, as it is highlighting how much money you have made in the current 24 hour cycle so far, while the revenue calculation is hourly. The fact it is a negative number only shows that you have yet to break even today on this attraction, **it is NOT showing any additional expense.** The important numbers are the expenses per hour and the revenue per hour. **As long as your Revenue per Hour is higher than the listed Expenses per Hour, your attraction is profitable.**

Using your example:

### Leaning Tower of Pisa

- Costs (C) $7320/day
- Average Revenue per Hour (Rph) = $319

**Expected Daily Profit (EdP) = (RpH X 24) - C**

EdP = (319 X 24) - 7320

EdP = (7656) - 7320

**EdP = 336**

So, at your current average revenue per hour, you can expect to make $336 every 24 hours. However, for the purpose of Simcity where your balance is calculated hourly, it is more useful to know how much you are making or losing per hour. That calculation is simply:

**Expected Hourly Profit (EhP) = EdP / 24**

EhP = 336 / 24

**EhP = $14**

You are making $14/hr off of this attraction, so therefore it is profitable but not wildly so. You should increase the transit options available to make it easier to get to, as well as zone more commercial around it to attract more tourists and shoppers to the general area.

Comment: Okay, nice to know that it can never cost more than $305/hr. I'm not sure what's up with my tourists. I think a meteor or something destroyed my villain's skyscraper which brought in some, and I also bulldozed my airport after finding out how to recycle water (it was next to my waste treatment plant). But even before those things happened, the number of visitors to the attractions was always in a high flux. One trick I found was that every time I hold an event at the stadium my city is full of tourists, and the attractions max out their capacities.

Comment: You're correct. The best way to pull in tourist is through events, provided you have the mass transit to move them about. I like to use the globe theatre in smaller cities.