# How is profit from gambling paid out?

Tags: simcity-2013

Normally, with a trade port, the payment for your wares shows up all few days when they sell.

With gambling however, this is different. There is no direct payout as far as I can see and it is also not in the budget window at all.

When I look at a Casino or Gambling House, it tells me what I earn per day but also what I pay or earn per hour.

So when does the game exactly take away or add the money I lose or make via gambling?

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per rs232's answer.

Comment: @pppery VTLO. It's no good practice to close questions because they have the same answer, and it seems the in-game feedback of both scenarios is sufficiently different.

Comment: Agree with @Joachim If anything, the answer should be deleted as "link-only"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this answer to a similar question about how tourism money goes to your city coffers will help explain it.  They are likely very similar, if not identical.

[Does profit from the tourist attraction culture buildings go to the city coffers?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/109202/does-profit-from-the-tourist-attraction-culture-buildings-go-to-the-city-coffers)